# Control multiple bots stop interfering discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have multiple bots in my code one named client and the other one clientHook. the login using different tokens and intents. Somehow when I do this:

```js
clientHook.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot && message.content.startsWith("You casted")) {
        joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: Fishgame[castStrength],
            guildId: "1148582522633072741",
            adapterCreator: client.guilds.cache.get("1148582522633072741").voiceAdapterCreator,
        });
    }
});
```

My Normal client does it not my clientHook. Its very confusing, I checked all the tokens and everything.

Comment: the joinVoiceChannel function is probably coming from your other client?

Comment: How would I change it?

Comment: ...import it from your other bot

Answer (score 0):

On **line 6**: replace `client.guilds.cache.get` with `clientHook.guilds.cache.get`.

If this doesn't work for you, the code behind `joinVoiceChannel()` is to blame. In this scenario you should add another parameter to the function that allows you to pass through a client object.

E.g: `joinVoiceChannel(jsonParams, client)`.